# Title Case Validation for my Form fill apge

Tags: regex, validation

I have company input field in my form and I would like to validate teh Company name like below.

1. Company name should be the title case
2. It should be allow the special char and symbol.

I have used the below regx but not help.

```
REGEX(Name, "([A-Z]([a-z])+\\s?)+")
```

Please help me to resolve.

e.g : 
Super Company (pvt Ltd).
 dont check the title case with n the bracket.

Facebook Company - Pvt. Ltd , please check the "F" and "C" and allow the - and check the "L" and "P"

Answer (score 0):

```js
([A-Z](\w*[\W\s]+))+
```

[Try that one out](https://regex101.com/r/aN2pY7/1) it's supposed to match stuff as long as you have caps on the first letter.... which means that for your example the name

> Super Company (pvt Ltd).

Should actually be "Super Company (**P**vt Ltd)." in order for this to work... can probably add something to allow small caps inside brakets but not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Yes it si works fine but it was not work for this name :  Pyramid Construction - Ltd

Comment: You just need to add whatever special char you want to support inside the list like for the - it becomes like this:

([A-Z](\w*[\W\s-]+))+

try here: https://regex101.com/r/pB9eI2/1

Comment: If you are validating a single filed be sure to add ^ and $ to the begining and end of the regex to mark that it must be a full phrase